# GWT Alternative Cell

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2, gwt-celltable

How to create [GWT Cells](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/Cell.html) alternatively at my [Columns](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html) of [Cell Table](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) ?
For instance: I have one column and **even rows** will show [Button Cells](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html) and **odd rows** will show [Text Cells](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/TextCell.html).
Can it be possible ? If yes , how can I figure it out ? Thanks for any suggestions !

Below image is an example ....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a [custom cell](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html), which would render differently based on its context:

```
@Override
public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    if (context.getIndex() & 1 == 0) {
        // render one way
    } else {
        // render the other way
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir now I got it! Thanks greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sir @AndreiVolgin. Now I got it. Here is my code as sir *Andrei Volgin*'s answer.

```
        ButtonCell buttonCellEdit = new ButtonCell() {
        @Override
        public void render(final Context context, final SafeHtml data, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("It is row " + i);
            }
            else {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type=\"button\" class=\"gwt-Button btn btnBlue\" tabindex=\"-1\">");
                if (data != null) {
                    sb.append(data);
                }
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("</button>");
            }
        }
    };
```